# cannot be applied to java.lang.double

Tags: java, android, class, methods

I'm making an app to work out how much tax you pay.
The user enters the salary and the code goes and works it out and returns the value.
I am having trouble using the methods that are in different classes like tax.   The error occurs on the `tax tax1 = new tax(salaryAmount);` line.
A red line appears and says, "cannot be applied to double".

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public void convert() {
    EditText salaryAmountEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.salaryAmountEditText);
    double salaryAmount = Double.parseDouble(salaryAmountEditText.toString());
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tax tax1 = new tax(salaryAmount);
    Double pocketAmount = salaryAmount - tax1 ;

}
```

```
public class tax {

    public double Tax(double money) {
        Double tax1;
        if (money < 11000) {
            tax1 = 0.0;
        } else if ( 11000 < money && money<45000) {
            tax1 = (money -11000)*0.2;
        } else if(45000 < money && money<150000){
            tax1 = 68000 + ((money - 45000)*0.4);
        } else {
            tax1 = 6800 + 42000 + ( (money - 150000)*0.45 );
        }
        return tax1;
    }

}
```

Comment: it says what can not be applied to double, check that part of the error message too

Comment: Are you missing the tax constructor?

Comment: you are using `Tax`  ,method names are case sensitive

Comment: @Stultuske it says tax() in tax cannot be applied to the double. Cheers

Comment: Once you get this to compile, it'll still crash at `salaryAmountEditText.toString()` because you're missing a `getText()`

Comment: @cricket_007 yup that's one more error.

Comment: Also, `salaryAmount - tax1` won't work

Comment: @cricket_007 many thanks for your reply. May I ask why it won't work? tax as a method should return a double and salaryAmount is a double?

Comment: Your method returns a double, your code says its a tax object. `tax tax1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a method, but you called a constructor. In order to call your method, you do need an instance (by calling a constructor), but constructors have no return types...

In other words, you need this

```
tax t = new tax();
double tax1 = t.Tax(salaryAmount);
```

An alternative option, though, you can use a `static` method. (As an aside, you really don't even need a separate class, since you could move that method into your Activity)

```
public class tax {

    public static double Tax(double money) {
```

And to calculate it, you would use like this.

```
double tax1 = tax.Tax(salaryAmount);
double pocketAmount = salaryAmount - tax1 ;
```

Since your method returns a double, it's not an instance of the  `tax` class, so you're able to do the subtraction

Comment: This has solved it! Thank you very much cricket_007, very clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Your class `tax` does not have a constructor that accepts a `double` as an input parameter (i.e)

```
public tax(Double tax){}
```

Also you are breaking Java convention by having a class's name in all lowercase and it's method's one with a capital. Use camelCase instead for methods, and use a capital for the starting letter of all classes.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I accept I'm a beginner and do make mistakes. I changed the class so that it looks like this: **public class tax(double tax){}**, such as what you have done, the whole class has a red line saying : 'class' or 'interface' expected.

Comment: @math remove `class`

Comment: @cricket_007's answer is much more detailed, use his!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got confused between your class and the methods contained within it.

The method `public double Tax(double salaryAmount)` is not static, and therefore requires an instance of the object to be called upon.

So your code would look like this:

`tax tax1 = new tax();
double computedTax = tax1.Tax(salaryAmount);`

On a side note, convention is to capitalise the class name, and camelCase method names. This would make your class look like `public class Tax`, and your method signature `public double tax(double salaryAmount)`